# why guest additions needs xorgs packages

Tags: debian, vagrant, xorg

trying to install a vagrant i figured out a problem.

I tried to install a debian jessie os and followed procedure from several docs.

I choosed not to install a desktop environment.

During the process i had to install linux headers and then guest additions wich failed many times.

googling it it was due to the lack of 2 xorg package.

I don't get why you need to have this xorg packages to install properly guest additions.

Does any one has any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the guest-additions mainly provide xorg drivers.

If you are not running an X-server, there is little reason to install them.

Comment: i guess it was obvious because i get downvoted but i'm not a linux pro